# Call ID from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I'm building a TinyMCE custom dropdown menu in WordPress. I am able to call a form into the thickbox modal window if I include the form in the same javascript file as the dropdown menu, but I want to be able to call a form from an external javascript file. Here's the code that allows me to call it inline:

```
b.add({
title:"MyLink","class":"tmce-mylink",onclick:function(){
var width = jQuery(window).width(), H = jQuery(window).height(), W = ( 720 < width ) ? 720 : width; 
W = W - 80; 
H = H - 80; 
tb_show( 'MyLink', '#TB_inline?width=' + W + '&height=' + H + '&inlineId=mylink-form' );
}
}
);
```

The key component there is this line:

```
tb_show( 'MyLink', '#TB_inline?width=' + W + '&height=' + H + '&inlineId=mylink-form'
```

How can I modify this to call the form id from an external JS file into the TB modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that as long as the form is registered I can call it from anywhere.